# IAP Purchase Complete

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to write an if statement after a completed purchase. I'm using [this](https://github.com/thielCole/ionic-iap2/blob/master/src/pages/about/about.ts) tutorial.

```
purchase() {
  if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) { return };

  let productId;

  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    productId = this.product.appleProductID;
  } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
    productId = this.product.googleProductID;
  }

  console.log('Products: ' + JSON.stringify(this.store.products));
  console.log('Ordering From Store: ' + productId);
  try {
    let product = this.store.get(productId);
    console.log('Product Info: ' + JSON.stringify(product));
    let order = await this.store.order(productId);
    alert('Finished Purchase');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error Ordering ' + JSON.stringify(err));
  }
}
```

I'm trying to load a new screen with data (content and gameGear), once the user completes the purchase:

```
goToReference() {
  this.purchase();
  if(this.purchase() === 'Finished Purchase'){
    this.navCtrl.push(ReferencePage,{
      content: this.content,
      gameGear: this.gameGear
    });
  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

However the error I keep getting is:

> Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'Promise' and 'string'.

Not sure how to get around this issue or if there's easier syntax to fire off the `this.purchase()` once the purchase has been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting remark let me say that your code executes a purchase twice, due to `purchase` being called two times.

```
this.purchase();
if(this.purchase() === 'Finished Purchase')
```

The error indicates that you are comparing the returned value of the `purchase` function with the `'Finished Purchase'` string. There are two things to note in your current code that cause this:

1. The `purchase` function is asynchronous (even though it seems you removed the async keyword from your code sample). The async function returns a `Promise`. You can see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) to understand more about asynchronicity and promises.
2. You're not returning the `'Finished Purchase'` string, but are showing a browser alert popup. Therefore in fact the returned value of `purchase` is `void`, combined with promises the exact type becomes `Promise<void>`.

I'm going to assume you want `purchase` to return whether or not the purchase succeeded. For the example I remove all cluttering code:

```
async purchase() {
  try {
    let order = await this.store.order(productId);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}

async goToReference() {
  if(await this.purchase()) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ReferencePage,{
      content: this.content,
      gameGear: this.gameGear
    });
  }
}
```

Above, the return type of `purchase` is `Promise<boolean>`.